# Running a task asynchronously on Weblogic

Tags: java, asynchronous, weblogic

I'm developing a web application and one of it's features is to send email notifications once the form is submitted. I wonder what's the easiest/best way of sending them asynchronously. I'd like to get the response from the server instantly and invoke an email sending job in the background not waiting for it to finish.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMS to send mails asynchronously.

[Here is a question about this befure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625361/why-jms-to-send-mail-by-java-mail)

[You can look at thtis link fopr simple JMS Queue implemantation](https://blogs.oracle.com/soaproactive/entry/how_to_create_a_simple)